# Blackberry Webworks 2.0 viewport tag not working

Tags: viewport, blackberry-webworks

I'm creating an application with BlackBerry Webworks 2.0 for the BlackBerry Z10. With bbui-min.js version 0.9.6.932.

I cannot seem to change the viewport of the appication. I want to be able to zoom in which usually works with the following viewport definition in my html:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=yes"/>
```

This tag doesn't seem to have any influence when using the bb.init() function. If I don't call the bb.init() function the viewport tag does have influence.

This is probably because in 0.9.4 the following has been implemented:

> You no longer specify a viewport meta tag in your main index.htm. This
>   is now supplied by the toolkit at runtime based on the OS version.

See: http://devblog.blackberry.com/2012/10/bbui-js-update/

Now the question: How do I change the viewport, because I would really like to specify it myself.

Answer (score 1):

I will first explain why you shouldn't do that and then show you a way of achieving it if you still want to go ahead:

bbUI.js is a framework that allows you to provide a native experience using web languages. Zooming in is not a desired features in a native application for several reasons, one of them being that it's ugly and results in a poor user experience. If you need the capability of zooming in a specific component instead of the whole app there are workarounds available but you shouldn't touch the viewport.

Simply put: it's not the native experience your user would like to have.

If you are not concerned about the user experience and want to fully control the viewport then you need to modify the bbUI.js file, specifically from line 73: https://github.com/blackberry/bbUI.js/blob/master/pkg/bb10/bbui.js

The code looks like

```
// Check if a viewport tags exist and remove them, We'll add the bbUI friendly one 
    var viewports = document.head.querySelectorAll('meta[name=viewport]'),
        i;
    for (i = 0; i < viewports.length; i++) {
        try {
            document.head.removeChild(viewports[i]);
        } catch (ex) {
            // Throw away the error
        }
    }           

    // Set our meta tags for content scaling
    var meta = document.createElement('meta');
    meta.setAttribute('name','viewport');
    if (!bb.device.is1024x600) { 
        meta.setAttribute('content','initial-scale='+ (1/window.devicePixelRatio) +',user-scalable=no');
    } else {
        meta.setAttribute('content','initial-scale=1.0,width=device-width,user-scalable=no,target-densitydpi=device-dpi');
    }
```

as you can see the snippet removes the viewport that you define and replaces it with a custom one. Make your modifications and use this file instead of the original one.